# What are tensorflow frozen_inference_graph.pb files in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I found these files are graph files which weight set of parameters backed in to the graph as constants.

I have these questions

1. What are .pb file format. Is it binary ?
2. Can I explore the structure of the graph with this kind of format more like how many layers , name scopes etc

Answer (score 3):

1. This is protobuf format
2. Yes you can, check [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is protobuf format ?  I know it's a data type. Can you elaborate it more.

Comment: "Protocol buffers are a language-neutral, platform-neutral extensible mechanism for serializing structured data. " from [this site](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Comment: text_format.Merge(f.read(), graph_def) 

The above method is for lading data in to the graph_def object as in the text form right ? 

But then our f.read() should be in .pbtx format right? 

I want to know if the format is .pb can I visualize the graph ?